# Using VBA to track changes in Excel - Suggestions?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large number  of workbooks (~4500), each with four sheets, which I need to be able to track changes in. Currently I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    vnew = Target.Value
    vaddress = Target.Address
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    vold = Target.Value
    If vold = "" Then
        Target.Value = vnew
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'make this whatever color you want for when it used to be blank
    ElseIf vold <> vnew Then
        Target.Value = vnew
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) 'make this whatever color you want for when the cell changed
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this is buggy for users trying to copy and paste blocks of text and is also not ideal in that it stops the ability to use undo. We have thought about using conditional formatting but having to copy all four sheets into "*_old" sheets, or something like that to have something to compare to, doesn't seem feasible for the sheer number of workbooks we have to work with.

We also can't use the built in Excel track changes due to project needs. We need cells to be highlighted.

Does anyone have any recommendations or tried-and-true methods for this?

BTW, we are using Python to get the macros into the workbooks in large batches right now.

Comment: You can take a look here: http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/24 I believe Excel has some systems built in to handle tracking changes

Comment: Ah, yes forgot to mention that we looked into that also and we actually need things highlighted unfortunately. Thanks so much though! I appreciate the response.

Comment: I think the best way to track changes is going to be to store a copy of the original data. I know it's a lot of sheets to store, but there is never going to be a surefire way to know what has changed unless you keep track of where you started.